# Combining two unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables , Book(Bookid ,title) And Movie(Movieid, title) and checkout(memberid,bookid,movieid).

```
Movie:

id          title
----------  -------------
1           Life of Brian
2           Airplane
3           Rush
4           Day of the De
5           Star Wars
6           Thin Red Line
7           Crouching Tig
8           Lawrence of A
9           Office Space

Book:

id          title
----------  ----------
1           Life of Pi
2           Fellowship
3           Two Towers
4           Dune
5           The Hobbit
6           1984
7           Tom Sawyer
8           Catcher in
9           To Kill a
10          Domain Dri

Checkout:

member_id   book_id     movie_id
----------  ----------  ----------
6           1
1           3
2           4
1           5
1                       1
7                       2
6                       3
8                       4
6                       5
```

I want to select all books and movies that have not been checked out.

Currently I am using these queries.

```
create table MoviesNotCheckedOut (MovieID integer, MovieName text);

    Insert Into MoviesNotCheckedOut 
    select m.id, m.title from movie m where 
    m.id NOT IN  
    (select c.member_id from checkout_item c);

    create table BooksNotCheckedOut (BookID integer, BookName text);

    Insert Into BooksNotCheckedOut 
    select b.id, b.title from book b where 
    b.id NOT IN  
    (select c.member_id from checkout_item c);

create table BooksAndMoviesNotCheckedOut(BookID integer, BookName text, MovieID integer, MovieName text);

insert into BooksAndMoviesNotCheckedOut
select b.BookID,b.BookName,m.MovieID,m.MovieName from BooksNotCheckedOut b, MoviesNotCheckedOut m;
```

But on displaying I am getting duplicates like this:

```
BookID      BookName    MovieID     MovieName
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
3           Two Towers  3           Rush
3           Two Towers  4           Day of the
3           Two Towers  5           Star Wars
3           Two Towers  9           Office Spa
4           Dune        3           Rush
4           Dune        4           Day of the
4           Dune        5           Star Wars
4           Dune        9           Office Spa
5           The Hobbit  3           Rush
5           The Hobbit  4           Day of the
5           The Hobbit  5           Star Wars
5           The Hobbit  9           Office Spa
9           To Kill a   3           Rush
9           To Kill a   4           Day of the
9           To Kill a   5           Star Wars
9           To Kill a   9           Office Spa
10          Domain Dri  3           Rush
10          Domain Dri  4           Day of the
10          Domain Dri  5           Star Wars
10          Domain Dri  9           Office Spa
```

How do I remove the duplicates. I want to display it as something like this:

```
BookID     BookName     MovieID     MovieName
_ _ _      _ _ _ _      _ _ _ _     _ _ _ _ _ _

1           xxxx          4          yyyy
```

Comment: You should spend some time learning how joins work.

Comment: Dont I need  a relation to join two tables?? There is no relation here between Books and Movies

Comment: "from BooksNotCheckedOut b, MoviesNotCheckedOut m" is a join.

Comment: The only join for unrelated tables is CROSS JOIN , i think. And that gives the same result.

Comment: Yes it is a join. But it does not achieve the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`; however, you should do this as two columns:

```
select 'movie' as which, m.id, m.title
from movie m
where not exists (select 1 from checkout co where co.movieid = m.id)
union all
select 'book' as which, b.id, b.title
from book b 
where not exists (select 1 from checkout co where co.bookid = b.id);
```

Comment: what does `select 1` mean ??

Comment: @leoOrion When checking for the existence of a row, it does not matter whether you select some column(s) or `*` or simply `1`. Typically, `1` is used to show that you do not care, and as an optimization to avoid having to access the actual table when the existence of the row can already be implied from some index entry.

Comment: so 1 can mean "any number of columns but I dont care " ??

Comment: also does `which` refer to what is given in the quotes ??

Comment: @leoOrion . . . The "1" is just saying that a row is returned.  The `which` describes whether the returned row is a book or a movie.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This Helped